# Convert into SF in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert spatial data from a CDC/HHS data on hospital capacity, as downloadable from here:

https://healthdata.gov/Hospital/COVID-19-Reported-Patient-Impact-and-Hospital-Capa/anag-cw7u

I'm trying to import it as an CSV, transform it, and then turn it into a shapefile. The file has a field, termed geocoded_hospital_address, that I am trying to use to convert the dataset. It is in POINT(longitude, latitude) format e.g., "POINT (-100.01382, 37.441504)". I am used to using two variables (longitude/latitude) under the coords option, and I cannot get the "sf_column_name" option to work for me or decompose the field into two parts:

```
test_sf<-COVID_19_Reported_Patient_Impact_and_Hospital_Capacity_by_Facility%>%
+   st_as_sf(sf_column_name="geocoded_hospital_address", crs=4326)
Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : 
  no simple features geometry column present
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That "POINT" format is the "Well Known Text" (WKT) format and is commonly used for geographic data representation and interchange in text files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why using the sf_column_name argument is not working. There are empty geometries. If you look at `hpi$geocoded_hospital_address[1:100]` you will see many records that are coded as "". I am using grep to remove these observations but,the `sf::st_as_sf` call is still not working. As such, I am reading the geometry, directly from the WKT column, to an sfc geometry object then coercing to sf.

```
library(sf)
hpi <- read.csv("COVID_19_Reported_Patient_Impact_and_Hospital_Capacity_by_Facility.csv")
  hpi <- hpi[grep("POINT", hpi$geocoded_hospital_address),]
    hpi <- st_as_sf(st_as_sfc(hpi$geocoded_hospital_address, crs = 4326), hpi)
```

Now, that said, I could not help but notice that on the website that you pointed us to, on the right-side radio "export" button there is a shapefile option that may save you some headaches.

Comment: Thanks! helpful. I was having trouble downloading the shapefile until recently, and there's a fair amount of manipulation that I thought would be easier to accomplish as a CSV file, though I'm still new at this. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: There's a GDAL driver option that reads a WKT column in a CSV.

Answer (score 2):

You can read this directly using `st_read` with the GDAL option that tells the CSV driver that there's a WKT geometry string in a column. Here's a test on the first 500 lines:

```
> p = st_read("./Covid.500.csv", 
      options="GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES=geocoded_hospital_address",
      crs=4326)
```

Note the warning of the empty geometries:

```
options:        GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES=geocoded_hospital_address 
Reading layer `Covid.500' from data source 
  `/nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/Covid.500.csv' using driver `CSV'
replacing null geometries with empty geometries
Simple feature collection with 499 features and 127 fields (with 54 geometries empty)
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -157.8998 ymin: 18.20271 xmax: -67.14017 ymax: 64.83234
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
```

499 features because the first line is the header. Now tested and working on the full data set (takes a minute).